# faster way to save multi-dim numpy array in self-describing format such as json

Tags: json, python-3.x, numpy, serialization, pickle

I am looking for fast way to save multi dimensional array in self-describing format such as json. As the article said, the saving format could be self-describing (e.g. json, yaml, csv) or not self-describing (e.g. pickle, protobuf, hdf5).
https://medium.com/@shmulikamar/python-serialization-benchmarks-8e5bb700530b

First come up to my mind was json. So I compared dump/load time of json format versus pickle and npy. The comparison result is as follows, which shows using json at least by standard library is too inefficient.

Does anybody know other alternative self-describing format or fast way to serialize/de-serialize ?

```
pickle dump: 0.011399507522583008
pickle load: 0.01577591896057129
npy dump: 0.006514072418212891
npy load: 0.004297971725463867
json dump: 4.027008533477783
json load: 0.6741242408752441
```

```py
import json
import time
import pickle
import uuid
import numpy as np

# my data is like 100 image sequence
image_seq = np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(100, 3, 224, 224), dtype=np.uint8)


# benchmark for pickle
ts = time.time()
pickle_file = "/tmp/{}.pickle".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
with open(pickle_file, "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(image_seq, f)
print("pickle dump:", time.time() - ts)

with open(pickle_file, "rb") as f:
    pickle.load(f)
print("pickle load:", time.time() - ts)


# benchmark for npy
npy_file = "/tmp/{}.npy".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
ts = time.time()
np.save(npy_file, image_seq)
print("npy dump:", time.time() - ts)

ts = time.time()
np.load(npy_file)
print("npy load:", time.time() - ts)


# benchmark for json
ts = time.time()
json_file = "/tmp/{}.json".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
with open(json_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(image_seq.flatten().tolist(), f)
print("json dump:", time.time() - ts)

ts = time.time()
with open(json_file, "r") as f:
    json.load(f)
print("json load:", time.time() - ts)
```

Comment: It's confusing that you use `np.save()` but log it as "npy dump".  NumPy has a `dump()` function but it writes pickle format which is slower than the `np.save()` you're actually using.

Comment: A `npy` format has a header block describing shape and dtype, and a data buffer block. It is as close as we can get to an actual array in memory.  `pickle` also uses the `npy` format, but with an added python layer.  HDF5 (via `h5py`) saves similar information but in a more language independent manner.  Formats like JSON, xml, csv, yaml don't save numpy arrays directly, but rather do some sort of conversion to lists and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.save()` already gives you a self describing file, and as you have shown it is very fast.  If you want speed and self description, it is a great choice.

Text based formats like JSON or CSV will always be slower than binary ones like what `np.save()` gives you.